# Bash - not enough arguments

Tags: bash

I have never used bash before but I am trying to understand this piece of code. The script is supposed to display all log in names, full names and their user-ids. However, whenever I run I can not get past the first if statement and if I delete the statement, it does not work.

```
#!/bin/bash 
if [ $# -lt 1 ]; 
   then 
   printf "Not enough arguments - %d\n" $# 
   exit 0 
   fi 

typeset user="" 
typeset name="" 
typeset passwdEntry="" 
while [ $# -ge 1 ]; 
   do 
   user=$1 
   shift 
   name="" 
   passwdEntry=`grep -e ^$user /etc/passwd 2>/dev/null` 
   if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then 
   name=`echo $passwdEntry|awk -F ':' '{print $5}'` 
fi 
echo "$user $name" 
done
```

Comment: Well, the script wants at least one argument.

Comment: it checks the number of arguments and if there's no argument it'll exit. How did you run the script?

Comment: I don't know if it matters but the first semi-column `;` is not necessary. Does it hurt?

Comment: @Djee That script is *full* of unnecessary and strange things.

Comment: @Biffen: I am wondering what the OP means by s/he cannot pass beyond the first statement. Hence my worry.

Comment: @Djee I bet they're just not providing any arguments when running the script.

Comment: @Biffen yup thats my issue

Comment: @John From what I can tell, the script gets names of users, each user provided as an argument. If you don't give it any arguments, there's not much the script can do. Is anything still unclear?

Comment: @Biffen i just do not get how you would add the argument

Comment: @John Sounds like a shell tutorial would be in order. In short: `your-script.sh arg1 arg2`.

Comment: This might help now and in the future: [explainshell.com](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=[+%24%23+-lt+1+])

Comment: The script is using old techniques (like backticks `` ), some suited to the AT&T Korn shell (`typeset`) and some the old Bourne shell (the arithmetic comparisons).    This is not a good example to learn from!

Answer (score 4):

`$#` means "the number of arguments to the current Bash program", and `$1` means "the first argument to the current Bash program".

So your problem is that you're not passing any arguments to the program; for example, instead of something like this:

```
./foo.sh
```

you'll need to write something like this:

```
./foo.sh USERNAME
```

As you are new to Bash, I highly recommend skimming and bookmarking the *Bash Reference Manual*, http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html. It's all on a single page, so you can use your browser's "find in page" function (typically `Ctrl+F`) to search for things.